# What is the technical term for a hardware message authentication code generator IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, encryption

I am looking for a way to identify devices I build.

Basically I am looking for a chip to which I can write a non-recoverable secret and that uses this secret to then "sign" messages I send to it and returns the signed message to me.

Cryptographically, I imagine the chip would generate a message authentication code (MAC).

I am not particular regarding the algorithm used. Coming from a programming background, a HMAC implementation or concatenated SHA3 hashing are my naive ideas. That said, I do not need anything bullet proof. Just something to make forging non-trivial.

While we are at it, are there any cheap chinese solutions?

Comment: Basically what you are asking is what to buy. Some MCUs have these kind of features built-in, or can be done in software, so it's possible you don't have to buy anything. Do note that secure crypto MCUs may need some licencing to buy them and they may be more expensive due to the features you need, and then there may be some export issues to countries where you are not supposed to export cryptographic technology.

Answer (score 0):

The generic term is ["secure microcontroller".](https://www.st.com/en/secure-mcus.html) Available from various manufacturers such as ST, NXP etc.

You can also do this with SIMs (although the programming interface is horrendous) and various sorts of smartcard.